# How can I add Komodo to my bottom panel?

Tags: opensuse, komodo

I've installed Komodo on my Open Suse 12.2 KDE desktop but I don't have a menu entry in my start menu? I've followed the installation instruction at http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/install.html#Installing_Komodo_on_Linux but there isn't any readme to install a start menu? When I run Komodo from a shell it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it: Right click an empty place from the bottom panel and click add miniprogram. Look for the quickstarter miniprogram and left click it. Now you should get a  quickstarter miniprogram in the panel with a default icon for firefox and dolphin. Of course I deleted the firefox icon by right click it and click delete. To add Komodo right click the miniprogram and left click add starter. Now you can see a dialog box asking for the name of the program and a tree with all registered programs. I typed komodo into the input box and confirmed my selection. Problem solved!